# A throwaway riddle

Tags: riddle, history

My first followed a schism
Of proto-Protestantism
My second preceded a war
Of a decade and a score
My third was ready for bed
Possibly done by the Reds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> [The Defenestrations of Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague)

It is "A Throwaway Riddle" because

> It's all about people being thrown out of windows. Fortunately for me, when I was defenestrated at college (earning a lifelong interest in such things), it was from a bar on the ground floor.

per Wikipedia:

The First ...

> ... Defenestration of Prague involved the killing of seven members of the city council by a crowd of Czech Hussites on 30 July 1419 - "a schism of proto-Protestantism"

The Second ...

> ... Defenestration of Prague precipitated the Thirty Years' War - "a war of a decade and a score"

The Third ...

> ... defenestration of Prague has been used to describe the death of Jan Masaryk, who was found below the bathroom window ("ready for bed") of the building of the Czechoslovak Ministry of Foreign Affairs on 10 March 1948.  It was widely believed he was murdered, either by the nascent Communist government, or by the Soviet secret services - "Possibly done by the Reds".

Comment: Could you further elaborate in your description how it fits the clues of the riddle?

Comment: You got it! Before I award the tick, could you please elaborate just a little bit further on the Third (what it has to do with beds and Reds), and also mention how the title fits (should be pretty obvious)?